# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to start a new activity but I am getting this error for the activity which I want to start. This XML code is for the activity which I want to start.

Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.SandFoil.kaizen/com.SandFoil.kaizen.Registeration}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #94: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:495)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                         at com.SandFoil.kaizen.Registeration.onCreate(Registeration.java:11)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

and here's my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.SandFoil.kaizen.Registeration"
        android:id="@+id/activity_registeration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_name_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_phone_edittext"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="E-mail">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_email_edittext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Date of birth(dd/mm/yyyy)">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_date_of_birth_edittext"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Gender: "
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/registeration_gender_spinner"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                </Spinner>
            </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mother's name('N/A' if you are not a student)">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_mother_name_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Child's name('N/A' if you are not a parent)">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_child_name_edittext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/registeration_password_edittext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/capsule_button"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Googled all possible solutions but none worked. Can somebody please fix this and tell me something about this issue ?? And Here is the java file for this XML

```
package com.SandFoil.kaizen;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Registeration extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registeration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Java code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of "spinner" is wrong here in XML. I copied that code from somewhere on the internet. I will be editing this answer and posting the link to that wrong implementation for reference as soon as i find it again. Remove that "spinner" code from this XML and it will work.